# Rigorous proof of the Nyquist stability criterion

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, stability-theory

In systems theory one often deals with the frequency domain representation of systems instead of their time-domain representations:
If a LTI system $S$ is given by the convolution with $h(t) = Ce^{At}B$ for some $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$, then the Laplace transform of $h$ is given by the known formula $\hat{h}(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ and defined only on $$D = \{s \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Re}(s) > \max \operatorname{Re} \sigma(A)\},$$ where $\sigma(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$.
However, in many theorems in system theory one uses the transfer function $G(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ and assumes it to be defined on $E = \mathbb{C} \setminus \sigma(A)$, i.e. $G$ is the analytical continuation of $\hat{h}$ from $D$ to $E$.

Since in the usual proof of the Nyquist stability theorem one uses the argument principle on the meromorphic function $G$ together with the contour $\Gamma = [-R,R]i \cup R e^{i[-\pi/2,\pi/2]}$ (for some $R > 0$) which includes parts of the imaginary axis, which are not part of the original domain $D$ if $h$ is unstable (i.e. $A$ has eigenvalues in the closed right hand plane), it is not clear how the absence of poles of the sensitivity $$\frac{1}{1+G}$$ implies the stability of the original feedback with the system $S$

> Question: What is a rigorous proof of this theorem that incorporates the domain $D$ of the original Laplace transform $\hat{h}$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "... it is not clear how the absence of poles of...".

Comment: @KBS By that I mean that the relation between the analytic continuation $G$ and the original system is not established, i.e. if $(1+G)^{-1}$ has no poles in the RHP, how does it then relate back to our original feedback interconnection (since $G$ is not our system, but $\hat{h}$)?

Comment: It actually does not matter here as what matters are the poles of the transfer function for establishing the stability of the system. Note that those poles are outside the region of convergence, yet those poles contain information about the system and need to be considered, whence the use of the analytical cinrunation.  The region of convergence is only here for recovering the correct impulse response from the Laplace transform. I will write a full answer when I have time and will be on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

What is important here is to characterize the location of the the poles of the closed-loop system in terms of the behavior of the open-loop transfer function. While it is true that the Laplace transform $\hat h(s)$ of the open-loop impulse response has a region of convergence, this region of convergence is only useful for recovering the impulse response $h(t)$ from its Laplace transform. Different regions of convergence for $\hat h(s)$ yield different functions $h(t)$ obtained from the inverse Laplace transform.

Another point is that if one consider the region of convergence as the domain of the Laplace transform $\hat h(s)$ of the impulse response $h(t)$, then $\hat h(s)$ has no poles. However, those poles contain crucial information about the behavior of the open-loop transfer and that of the closed-loop transfer. In fact the region of convergence just contains some information about the rightmost pole of the open-loop, which is not enough.

So, we need to extend $\hat h(s)$ to the whole complex plane except at the eigenvalues of $A$, which yields the transfer function $G(s)$.

The proof of the Nyquist using the argument principle is then routine from this point and can be found in many monographs.

---

I am open to comments and remarks. I will update this response based on them. This is just a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still don't quite understand how $G$ relates to our original system. As soon as we start to evaluate $G$ on the whole complex plane (minus the poles) we also start "using" other systems (i.e. systems which have the Laplace transform equal to $G$ but on other regions of convergence, e.g. $1/(s-1)$ is the Laplace transform of an unstable system for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$ and also the Laplace transform of a anticausal system for $\operatorname{Re}(s) < 1$). Why are we (mathematically) allowed to do that and conclude something about our initial system?

Comment: But there is no conceptual difference between those systems. They will behave the same way when put into an interconnection and the resulting poles for the closed-loop system will be the same. If you want to get the time-domain expression for the impulse response, just take the inverse Laplace transform of the transfer function considering the region of convergence that matches the physical properties of your system. For a causal system, that will be $\Re[s]>\alpha>0$ or the opposite for an anti-causal system as you rightly pointed out.

Comment: In the end the Nyquist criterion is just about the location of the poles of a complex-valued function, rational in the current case, describing the closed-loop system based on the location of the open-loop transfer functions and some winding number property. All the information is pretty much in the poles and the behavior of the function on particular contour. As I said the region of convergence is only there to make the integral converge and to find back the right impulse response.

Comment: But the anticausal system is stable and also has a different convolution kernel (which results in a different ROC), so it is different from our system right? The same is then true for the sensitivity of the two corresponding closed loops, which is defined on different ROC and is again different for both systems (and induces different convolution kernels). The only thing that relates the two systems is that they have the same analytical continuation of their Laplace transfrom, but why is that of any importance?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is of importance?

Comment: I meant that the causal and anticausal systems are really different in the time domain - just because their Laplace transform has the same analytic continuation (and hence the Bode plot) doesn't say that they have any other common properties, or does it?